# Short story: Detectives clone suspects in order to pull out information after killing them

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, clones

From what I remember, and I read it in the mid 2000s so I only remember the basic outline and minor details might not be correct:

A couple (or more) of detectives are interrogating a suspect who is tight lipped and stubborn. Some back and forth shows the suspects confidence against his interrogators tactics only for the detectives to reveal at the end that the mass of flesh and organs in the "bacta tank" behind him is his clone in the process of becoming whole. And they don't care if he doesn't open his mouth; he's of no value and they can keep cloning him until they could get their answers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Did you read this online, in a magazine or in an anthology?

Comment: @DavidW read it in a scifi magazine I borrowed from a local library. Unfortunately cant recall it's name

Comment: _Bacta tanks_ are a Star Wars thing. Was it a Star Wars story, or are you just using the phrase to mean the same sort of tank?

Comment: @JohnRennie no it's not from star Wars, just using it as a phrase. It was something similar to it in concept. Again my recollection of it is vague, it was definitely a  container where flesh and mass could be seen coming into form. I'm 60/40 on something like a bacta tank, tho it could have been a bathtub like container too